# Symplectic invariance of Hodge numbers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, hodge-theory, kahler-manifolds

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold. If $J$ is a $\omega$-compatible complex structure on $X$ then $(X,\omega,J)$ is a compact Kähler manifold and so has Hodge numbers $h^{p,q}$.

My question is: is it true that Hodge numbers are symplectic invariants, i.e. depend only on $(X,\omega)$ and not on the extra choice of a compatible complex structure $J$?

Remarks:

1) I assume that there exists $\omega$-compatible complex structures for $(X,\omega)$. My question makes sense only for these very special symplectic manifolds.

2) it is known that Hodge numbers are not topological or smooth invariants, see for example [Diffeomorphic Kähler manifolds with different Hodge numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42744/diffeomorphic-k%C3%A4hler-manifolds-with-different-hodge-number)

3) obviously, Hodge numbers are complex invariants: the Hodge numbers of the Kähler manifold $(X,J,\omega)$ only depend on the complex manifold $(X,J)$. My question is in the "orthogonal" direction, fixing $\omega$ and varying $J$.

4) Hodge numbers are constant in a smooth family of compact Kähler manifolds. So a first step could be:

Is there a symplectic manifold $(X,\omega)$ whose space of $\omega$-compatible complex structures is not connected?

(I vaguely remember having seen that the answer is yes but I am unable to find where). Of course, the space of almost complex structures compatible with a given symplectic structure is known to be connected (in fact contractible) but the difficulty comes from the integrability condition necessary to have complex structures.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42709/question-about-hodge-number